# OnDropFiles starts long-lasting function

Tags: drag-and-drop, wxwidgets, wxperl

using wxperl I want to start a long-lasting function after dragging files to my window. Here is my code for the DropTarget:

```
package FilesDropTarget;

use strict;
use Wx qw[:allclasses];
use base qw(Wx::FileDropTarget);

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $caller = shift;
  my $fref = shift;
  my $this = $class->SUPER::new( @_ );
  $this->{caller} = $caller;
  $this->{fref} = $fref;
  return $this;
}

sub OnDropFiles {
  my( $this, $x, $y, $files ) = @_;

  &{$this->{fref}}($this->{caller},@$files);

  return 1;
}
```

This module is used via

```
$frame->{TextControl}->SetDropTarget( FilesDropTarget->new($frame,\&runner) );
```

(OnDropFiles calls the function &runner() with the dropped files as parameter.)
Everything is fine, except that the drag-source window on Windows is blocked while function &runner() is working, which potentially is a long-lasting operation. The drag-source window becomes useable again after `OnDropFiles` returns 1, hence after &runner() is ready.

Are there chances to get the drag-source unblocked before &runner() has been finished?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't call the function immediately, but postpone doing this until the next event loop iteration. If 3.x [CallAfter()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a63c7351618fd77330d80a250b3719519) is wrapped by wxPerl, you should use it. If not, emulate it manually by using the usual `wxEVT_IDLE` trick: have a handler for this event checking a flag and calling your function if it's set (and resetting it) and just set this flag in your `OnDropFiles()`.